# How to modify side margins in front pages (declared in subenvironment)?

Tags: environments, margins, thesis

I'm about to submit my thesis and I just noticed the first pages have different sidemargins to the rest of the text :(. They are supposed to be 2.5cm and they apper of ~ 1in.

I tracked the problem to the different environments I declare for each of these pages but can't figure out how to change them back [I have looked around before asking but haven't find the solution], here's a brief example of one of the environments:

```
\newenvironment{myenvironment} {\thispagestyle{plain}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace{0cm}
  {\Large \bfseries TITLE}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
   \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}}
```

For some reason the above code overrides the margin settings of the rest of the document. I have tried to declare them inside the environment using `\setlength` and also the geometry package (`\newgeometry{top=X, bottom=Y}`) to no avail.

This is my first big LaTeX project so I'm probably missing something here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 2.5cm is about 0.98 inches, so you're drawing a thin line here. Second, your code includes `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}` which sets additional margins.

You can substitute `\begin{quote}` by `\list{}{\rightmargin=0pt \leftmargin=0pt}             \item\relax` and `\end{quote}` by `\endlist`. (not tested).

Comment: @Liz If you found the answer useful, please accept the answer by ticking the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Yous can use `geometry` package.

```
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

You can simply say `[margin=2.5cm]` to have all margins as 2.5cm. Change tha paper as you wish. 
In the middle if you want to change the lay out, you can use

```
\newgeometry{left=0.8in,right=0.8in,top=1in,bottom=1in}
```

and after some pages if you want old layout back, just say

```
\restoregeometry
```

For details run `texdoc geometry` from command prompt.